# Deploy and run plug in is missing in solidity

Tags: solidity, remix

I tried to search in inactive plugins , still not able to locate. Can anyone help. Earlier it was available but after some days, i logged into remix and was not able to find it. Can anyone help and also what may be the reason now its suddenly not available.
[image: Screenshot of the search results of the plugin]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether this is the best solution or not.

1. Backup all your contract file (IMPORTANT)
2. Open the developer tool by right click on the page, then select inspect
3. Go to application tab
4. Clear local storage, session storage, and cookies for https://remix.ethereum.org/
5. Refresh the page, at this step, remix will treat you as first time user, and the "Deploy & run transaction" will be back
6. Import your contract file